# All kinds of document viewer in react

Tags: reactjs, image, pdf, iframe, embed

I want to make document viewer in react which shows document in same page as popup as that is used in slack web application? It should view all kind of document files. Can anyone guide me  how to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Use a document viewer component for react like react-doc-viewer:-
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-doc-viewer

codesandbox:- https://codesandbox.io/s/zvk4j

Comment: I have already tried using document viewer component. My intention is to use either iframe or google docs viewer or any other document viewer and document opens on same page as pop up and upon cancelation the original page is shown (as similar to document viewer used in slack web application). I need to do these things using react.